# Suppressed exception as way to collect multiple exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have a recurring pattern in which I run multiple tasks in parallel, and either they all succeed or the whole process fails because of one of them. While I can determine that the process failed just after the first task exception, I must wait for them all to end before reporting an exception.

```
{
    List<Future<?>> futures = launchTasks();
    boolean anyProcessFailed = false;

    for (Future<?> future: futures)
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch(ExecutionException ex) {
            //This process failed
            anyProcessFailed=true;
        }

    if (anyProcessFailed) throw new Exception();
}
```

The above code works, but the exception thrown at the end has no reference to the exception(s) that caused it, may it be one or all.

Question is: **is it a good practice** to use `Throwable.addSuppressed` to implement the concept of *multiple causes of an exception* or should I implement my own `Exception` type that exposes a `Throwable[] getCauses()`?

I have read that suppressed exception, while having a public API, are meant only to be set by the JRE during a try-with-resources statement. In fact, try-with-resources is syntactic sugar for a plain old-school `try-finally` block

Example 1: the following code won't wait for other tasks to finish, so other threads will be left in the wild.

```
{
    List<Future<?>> futures = launchTasks();

    for (Future<?> future: futures)
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch(ExecutionException ex) {
            //This process failed
            throw new Exception(ex);
        }

}
```

Example 2: what I am doing currently

```
{
    List<Future<?>> futures = launchTasks();
    Exception ex = new Exception();

    for (Future<?> future: futures)
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch(ExecutionException e) {
            //This process failed
            ex.addSuppressed(e);
        }

    if (ex.getSuppressed().length > 0) throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's always a good practice to implement your own exception representing a really exceptional scenario in your code **if** it can have a meaningful data for the caller of your API. Otherwise using one of the general purpose exceptions in JDK would be a better choice. I think in the JavaDoc of the `addSuppressed` method, the try-finally scenario is mentioned as a sample usage of this method in JDK. You can of course use it for your scenario if it makes sense.

Comment: I had a similar question.  The java docs now state: "Note that programmer written code is also able to take advantage of calling this method in situations where there are multiple sibling exceptions and only one can be propagated."

Answer (score -1):

> Question is: is it a good practice to use Throwable.addSuppressed to implement the concept of multiple causes of an exception or should I implement my own Exception type that exposes a Throwable[] getCauses()?

1. No.  These are not "suppressed" exceptions in the sense that the term is used in the JLS and the `Throwable` API.
2. Yes, though I wouldn't call the property `causes`.

Comment: A generic instance of Exception was meant to be an example. I already have my specific exceptions